# Resolving circular dependencies in Scala

Tags: scala, initialization

I've been experimenting with circular dependencides in Scala.

```
object A {
  val value:Int = 5 * B.value
}

object B {
  val value:Int = 3 * A.value
}

object Main extends App{
  println(A.value)
  println(B.value)
}
```

execution results with

```
0
0
```

But i was expecting an error

Comment: with `-Xcheckinit` you get a scala.UninitializedFieldError at runtime

Comment: Is there anything for cyclic init problems causing deadlocks? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63149269/how-to-identify-get-automated-hints-with-cyclic-object-initialization-causing

Answer (score 2):

When values have circular dependencies, the compiler will not do any inlining and instead generates static initialisers and the initialisation will rely on the class loading order to evaluate the expression. [Check this out](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077382/core-java/when-a-constant-isn-t-really-a-constant.html).
To make it clearer, try addition rather than multiplication.

```
object A {
   val value:Int = 5 + B.value
 }

object B {
   val value:Int = 3 + A.value
 }

object Main extends App{

   println("A= "+A.value) // 8
   println("B = "+B.value) // 3
}
```

But if you swap the calls the result will be

```
object Main extends App{

   println("B= "+B.value) // 8
   println("A = "+A.value) // 5
}
```

Answer (score 1):

when i changed `val` to `def` or `lazy val` it results with stack overflow, as i was expecting initially

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.experiments.A$.value(Experiments.scala:8)
    at com.experiments.B$.value(Experiments.scala:12)
    at com.experiments.A$.value(Experiments.scala:8)
    at com.experiments.B$.value(Experiments.scala:12)
```

I guess, it is related with evaluation type, where `val` has call by value and `def` and `lazy val` have call by name. Because of that `A.value` and `B.value` expressions are ignored when using val